# Google Cloud platform - how to debug network usage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp

I have configured server on Google cloud. It worked stable, but since last 2 days I got unexpected high usage of "Network standard Data transfer out" which breaks my assumptions about costs.

I'd like to find out reason what exactly causes that big raise of cost, and how can I bring it back.

Can someone advice where I can search for reason of that sudden change?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: It appears that the cost is €1.80/day vs €.7/day?

Comment: True, and the green bar that made 0.01€ daily now makes over 1€ daily. I have no idea what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
As I learned, Google gives [200GB free traffic](https://cloud.google.com/network-tiers/pricing) monthly. My server sent about 11GB of traffic daily, so after 19 days it was consumed, and they started to change me for traffic.

Now I should optimize data going out, and fit into the free tier.

Answer (score 0):

First, take a look at metrics of various Google Cloud services available in Metrics Explorer. Here you can find list of all standard GCP metrics:

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp

This will help you get better understanding of what's going on. You will find metrics related to networking itself, as well as to network-related services e.g. Load Balancing.

You might also want to enable billing data export to BigQuery:

https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery